# How to execute two sql queries in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli-multi-query

I am trying to execute this code in a php page to store some data on my database.
The thing is that I want to **Insert** data, but due to a **foreign key constraint** it is impossible. So, in my php code I want to **execute two sql queries**. The first one to **disable foreign key checks** and the second one to **insert the data**.

When I try it in phpmyadmin it works. But manually. I would like to put it on php code.

This is my code. The parameter **$conexion is the one that executes my sql queries**.

Any ideas?

```
$sql = "SET foreign_key_checks=0";
$sql. = "INSERT INTO routes (title, distance, subtitle) VALUES ('".$_POST['title']."','".$_POST['distance']."', '".$_POST['subtitle']."');";

$conexion->multi_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid using `multi_query`. Sending a small query to the MySQL server doesn't really affect performance and does prevent kind of limit the effect of something like SQL injection.

In your case there's no need for `multi_query`. If you send two queries in a script, both go over on the same connection. The `SET` query affect the current connection.

```
// Protect against SQL injection
$title = $conexion->escape_string($_POST['title']);
$distance = $conexion->escape_string($_POST['distance']);
$subtitle = $conexion->escape_string($_POST['subtitle']);

// Execute queries
$conexion->query("SET forgeign_key_checks=0");
$conexion->query("INSERT INTO routes (title, distance, subtitle) VALUES ('$tittle', '$distance', '$subtitle')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the comment above, you need a semi-colon between your sql statements

multi_query  - Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.